# How to start child process in .net core console application

Tags: asp.net-core, process, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a dotnet core 2.2 console app.
I hosted it as windows service.(Service name: "MyService1")
If "MyService1" starts, I want to start child process(WebAPI.exe or any .exe)

I can do this using Process class.
Sample code:

```
webAPI = new Process();
webAPI.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
webAPI.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Project\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.2\publish\WebAPI.exe";
webAPI.Start();
```

But is there any other way without using Process class.